# Given an integer n, print all integers from 1 to 2^n. Why does this not prove that P!=NP?

Tags: algorithms, p-vs-np

I only just recently learned about the P=NP problem in introduction to algorithms class, and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it. I thought of this situation while cleaning my room today and couldn't think of a way to disprove it to myself. Perhaps it

Obviously, the algorithm described in the title would have to iterate 2^n times to print all numbers from 1 to 2^n. As a result, this algorithm would never be able to be done in polynomial time and P is indeed a proper subset of NP. What is the error in my reasoning here? Is it that this problem is not in NP?

Comment: How do you go from “this algorithm would never be able to be done in polynomial time” to “P is indeed a proper subset of NP”?

Comment: It is my (basic) understanding that the problems in NP are those not able to be solved in polynomial time. Thus, the described problem would be in NP, but definitely not in P because it can never be done in polynomial time.

Comment: NP is a particular set of problems, some of which we don't know how to do in polynomial time. It isn't just "not polynomial." Also, P and NP are sets of decision problems and "count to $2^n$" isn't a decision problem.

Answer (score 3):

NP is the set of problems that can be *verified* in polynomial time, i.e. there is a polynomial-time algorithm that can verify a purported solution. P is the set of problems that can be *solved* in polynomial time, i.e. there is a polynomial-time algorithm that can *find* a solution.

“The problems in NP are those not able to be solved in polynomial time” is completely wrong. This is not at all what NP means. The N in NP is for “nondeterministic”, not for “not”. A problem in NP may be solvable in polynomial time — P is a subset of NP. The question “P = NP?” is in fact whether *all* problems in NP are solvable in polynomial time.

The set of problems that cannot be solved in polynomial time is the complement of P.

Note that “problem” has a specific technical meaning: it's a [decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem), i.e. an function from some input space to $\{\mathrm{yes}, \mathrm{no}\}$.

Counting is not a decision problem, so it doesn't fit in the classification that includes P and NP.

If you found a decision problem that cannot be solved in less than $2^n$ steps where $n$ is the size of the input, then that problem would not be in P. It might not be in NP either: it would only be in NP if there was a way to verify a solution in polynomial time.